# Building Maven project without Maven

Tags: maven, java, building

I have Maven project, but on one of servers I must build it without Maven.
It's possible using standard JDK commands. Where can I see what commands Maven sent to JDK while building project?

Comment: Why do you need to build without Maven ?

Comment: No Maven on this environment, and I can't install it

Comment: And then building software? Sounds strange. Change to an environment where you can and create a EAR etc. and transfer only the EAR instead of the sources code...is better anyway..

Comment: I encountered the same problem. If the only role of Maven is dealing with dependencies, we can manually download .JAR files and add them to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution. Of course it's hardcode, and project is very small, but for me it is helpful

project structure:
*main folder*
- dependency (dir)
- module1 - src ...
- module2 - src ...
- manufest.template (file)
module2 have dependency of module1, module1 is compilied with JDK1.5, module2 with JDK1.6.

```
@echo off

set JODA=dependency\joda-time-1.6.2.jar
set EJB=dependency\ejb-api-3.0.jar
set PERSISTANCE_API=dependency\persistence-api-1.0.jar
set DEPENDENCIES=%EJB%;%JODA%;%PERSISTANCE_API%
set TEMP_FILE=temp
set PUBLIC_INTERFACE_CLASSES=target\target-module1
set CODEGEN_CLASSES=target\target-module2
mkdir target
mkdir %MODULE1_CLASSES%
mkdir %MODULE2_CLASSES%

dir module1\*.java /s /B > %TEMP_FILE%
%JAVA_HOME_1_5%\bin\javac -classpath %DEPENDENCIES%;%MODULE1_CLASSES% -d %MODULE1_CLASSES% @%TEMP_FILE%

dir module2\*.java /s /B > %TEMP_FILE%
%JAVA_HOME_1_6%\bin\javac -classpath %DEPENDENCIES%;%JAVA_HOME_1_6%\lib\tools.jar;%MODULE1_CLASSES%;%MODULE2_CLASSES% -d %MODULE2_CLASSES% @%TEMP_FILE%

jar cf module1.jar -C %MODULE1_CLASSES% .
jar cfm module2.jar manifest.template -C %MODULE2_CLASSES% .

rm %TEMP_FILE%
rm -r target
```

Answer (score 6):

Maven does a lot. There's no easy way to simulate what Maven does without Maven.

If you absolutely can't install maven on the server, build your artifacts on another server (or locally) and move them onto the server via scp.

That said: I have once had a similar scenario where I generated an RPM from Maven for a server that absolutely needed to run a local build but could not run Maven (network access prohibited). What I did was to put all dependencies in the RPM, plus an Ant distribution and an Ant build file. In the RPM install script, the dependencies were unpacked and the Ant script called. It worked, but it meant double work.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the dependencies from here: http://jar-download.com/online-maven-download-tool.php. Therefore you need no Maven installtion.

Comment: Please add some description, in case link goes down